# Changing camera in two different scenes in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, camera

I have a mobile game, and this game have two different scenes. I want to do in first scene the camera should be vertical, and in second scene the camera should be horizontal. However, when I change the scene the camera always be vertical. How can I fix this.

Comment: Have you called `DontDestroyOnLoad()` on your first scene's camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a script to your cameras and use the following to change the [screen orientation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html):

i.e. to set screen vertical

`Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;`